# How do I start over in EX Mode?

Tags: hard-reset

Okay, so I've beaten Hard Reset.

I heard that there's something called "EX Mode", which would allow me to re-play the game at a more challenging difficulty while keeping all my upgrades. Now I'd like to do this, but I can't really figure out how.

After I've beaten the final boss, the credits roll, and from there it's back to the main menu, with the last save file being right before the boss. I've tried simply starting a new game on the same profile, but at a harder difficulty, but that just starts me at zero.

How is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normally available via the "New Game" option.

In `Ex Mode` you do not continue the game as such, but start really from zero with all he stuff you gained in your normal playthrough.

Comment: Why, there it is. Seems a bit odd to group a New Game+ together with the difficulty options, but there you go.